# Why are the exact payoffs in deterministic adversarial games not important?

Tags: game-theory

I understand deterministic is when players give an input and it always have the same output. And adversarial means there is opposing players. But I don't understand why the exact payoffs are not important.

Comment: Could you flesh out your question a bit?  I'm not sure exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This was a practice exam question. The title of this question was all we were given. Is this not enough information to answer the question? Thanks for the quick reply :)

Comment: "Is this not enough information to answer the question?"  Yes.  We're not in your class, so we don't know the context in which it was asked.

Comment: We've covered prisoners dilemma, game strategies (nash equilibrium) etc. The question was given no more context than I have provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In many cases of economists cannot actually actually measure the statistic they are discussing.  For example, there is no measurable unit of utility (there is a "util" but it is not measurable).  Nonetheless, an economist can discuss an allocation that is better or worse than another allocation.  $U(a) > U(b) > U(c).$  What matters is the order of preference between the allocations, not the numbers or the formula assigned to $U(x)$

Similarly, in game theory, what matters is the preference for each outcome rather than the specific numbers in the pay-out matrix.